# Does using promises in node.js make node synchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

How does promises still retain async while giving sync effect?

I.e Promises can make sequential code execution, doesn’t that remove async?

Then, whats the point of node.js?

Answer (score 3):

No, promises do not make Node.js code run synchronous - promises allow you to write flows that *appear* synchronous.

When you do this:

```
console.log(1);
setTimeout(() => console.log(2));
console.log(3);
```

Node.js runs the code sequantially, first it logs 1, then it registers a function to happen after a timeout, then it logs 3. After a big when the timer fires - it executes its function and logs 2. No threads are involved.

With promises and async await, when you `await` you're explicitly telling Node.js "pause executing this function and continue when the promise I'm waiting for resolved". `pause executing` isn't the same as a thread blocking - no context switch happens at an operating system level - it just keeps track of the function and when the promise resolves it calls it.

Node is run with "our code - platform code" cycles, your code runs (until it ends, for example by hitting an await), then the platform code runs (for example, checking timers and I/O) and then that code can call your code (for example your suspended async function) again and run it.

Comment: what determines whether i should use promises vs async?

Comment: `async/await` is built _on top of promises_, when you're using async/await you _are_ using promises already :)

Comment: How will I write a large system that has login system + CRUD db calls.? This will mean I will have to write a LOT of promises. Refer me to tutorial/book that uses promises.

Comment: @sdfdsfsdf writing a lot of promises is fine, we have hundreds of thousands at once per server in production.